# Microsoft App Center build fails for iOS flutter project - get_navigation

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-app-center

The build was working fine before. I added a new UDID in the devices in App Developer account. Then I triggered a rebuild. Then I got the following error.

```
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading project.pbxproj
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
##[warning]Build agent connection lost
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           195.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/get-4.6.5/lib/get_navigation/src/routes/get_transition_mixin.dart:608:57: Error: Too few positional arguments: 6 required, 5 given.

Encountered error while building for device.
##[error]The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Bash failed with error: The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: Post Clone Script
##[section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)
```

I tried generating new provisioning profile and certificate and the build still fails in app center. This looks like it is related to `get` library. I did not change any dependencies. Also this package is not found in `pubspec.yaml`. It's added as a transitive dependency in `pubspec.lock`. The build is working fine when running locally in Xcode on device. Please help me on how to fix this. Thanks.